# Need to learn spring cloud microservices to be deployed on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud

Need to learn microservices developed with spring boot+spring cloud and to be deplpoyed on AWS , where to start from ? as of know I know spring boot but I know nothing about spring cloud and AWS

Is there any specific api given AWS to write spring microservices and deploy it on AWS  or spring cloud is enough ?

Thanks,
Vasu

Answer (score 0):

This is... not a great question as it's suppper broad. Entire books have been written about this topic.

Having said that, I'm going to point you at some of the books written about this topic: reading those should help you understand some of your currently unkwown unknowns and be able to get this done (and give you the background to ask more specific questions in the future).

- The [Spring Cloud AWS Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html) <-- discovered this about 6 months ago for some other stuff, it's suupppperr good
- [Manning's Spring Microservices In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-microservices-in-action) book. The Cloud and microservices is actually kind of hard, and requires some infrastructure you may not have thought about
- [Baeldung's Spring Cloud AWS - EC2 Introduction article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-aws-ec2). Their stuff is reaaallly good, you'll run into it a lot on the web when hunting for Spring questions.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can dockerize the spring boot/cloud applications.
1. Run on EC2 machine via a docker-compose (group of microservices).
2. Elastic Container Service.

Hope this helps.